# Solution diverges for Converging-Diverging Nozzle

Tags: fluid-mechanics, ansys, cfd, fluent

I am trying to run a CFD simulation for an ASTAR nozzle but cannot get the solution to converge.

These are the steps I took to try and run the simulation. I made the geometry in Solidworks and imported the Parasolid file into the geometry (careful to to select 2D for the analysis type) and generated it. In the meshing I applied edge sizings (with bias toward the walls) and face meshing to get a decent looking mesh with skewness below 0.6 for all parts. For the setup conditions I did:

General: changed type to density-based

Models: turned on Energy

Materials: in the fluid air I changed density to ideal-gas and viscosity to sutherland (with default settings)

Boundary conditions: set outlet to pressure-inlet at pressure of 3e5 Pa, pressure-outlet at 0 Pa, and walls are no-slip condition

I left all the other settings as is, initialized it and ran it for 500 iterations, but it just blew up and I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Any ideas or tips on what to check for this? I've attached an archived work file that has all the setup and information in case this proves useful.

Thanks!

Files can be found here: https://studentcommunity.ansys.com/thread/solution-diverges-for-converging-diverging-nozzle/?postbadges=true

Comment: Pressure you mentioned is Absolute or Gauge? And what is the reference pressure?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was gauge (I didn't modify anything about the pressure) with the reference pressure at 101325 Pa

Comment: I am trying to understand the case better. What is the total pressure / Inlet velocity?

Comment: Could you please share the pressure contour plots at the beginning, after 10 steps, at 450 steps and while diverging? If only possible :-)